# Meteor 1.2でのtest-packagesでエラー

Tags: meteor

Meteor 1.1で開発したパッケージで当時はテストが通っていたのですが、Meteor 1.2にアップデートしたところテストが通らなくなってしまいました。

```
meteor test-packages --release 1.1 ./
```

では問題ないのですが、

```
meteor test-packages --release 1.2 ./
```

ではエラーがでます。エラーメッセージは、

```
exception - message Template is not defined
```

です。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。

Meteor 1.2の変更点に

```
test-packages no longer includes any packages globally (no changes needed)
```

があるのですが、これが影響していました。

package.jsの`Package.onTest()`に

```
api.use('templating');
```

を追記したところ正常になりました。

`Package.onUse()`には同じものが書いてあるのでをそれが引き継がれていると思っていたのですが、そういうものではなかったようです。